# Saving leaflet map as image?

Tags: leaflet, plugins

1. My map is in a HTML page
2. Lots of markers will be placed on the map
3. I need to save this map with all the marker in a img (.png or .jpg/.jpeg preferably) format, not the entire HTML page

Is there a plug-in from leaflet which allows us to do such a thing ?

Comment: this looks promising: http://rowanwins.github.io/leaflet-easyPrint/

Comment: Simply you can take a screenshot of the map and save it as PNG, if this can solve your problem.

Comment: @ahmadhanb This can be a solution, but if something exits avoid screenshot, it can be better :)

and Revo, exactly what I was looking for :D

Comment: @Revo that is perfect, exactly waht I needed :D

Comment: @PolyGeo, it looks similar to me as [Saving Leaflet.js maps as a static image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345934/saving-leaflet-js-maps-as-a-static-image), do not you think so? Leaflet provides documentation on this topic [Print/export](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to this Official LeafletJS Documentation's Plugins Page:

https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport

Comment: Someone already hinted me toward this ;) They told me to use leaflet easy-print plug-in to save my map as an image.